# CNN with Python and Keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm new to machine learning and Keras. I made an Neural Network with Keras for regression looking like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(57, input_dim=44, kernel_initializer='normal', 
activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(45, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(35, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dense(18, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

My data after preprocessing has 44 dimensions, so could you please give me an example how could i make an CNN.

Originally it looks like this: https://scontent.fskp1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/40159383_10204721730878434_598395145989128192_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&_nc_eui2=AeEYA4Nb3gomElC9qt0kF6Ou86P7jidco_LeHxEkmCB0-oVA9YKVe9VAh41SF25YomKTqKdkS96E18-sTCBidxJdbml4OV7FvFuAOWxI4mRafQ&oh=e81f4f56ebdf15e9c6eefbb078b8a982&oe=5BFD4157

Comment: Why don't you use simple regression technique? rather than using CNN?

Comment: I have an assignment to compare DNN results with CNN results for this data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Convolution** neural network is not the best choice in this case. BTW you can do this thing easily with **Conv1d**:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(44, 100))
model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(50, kernel_size=1, strides=1))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
# model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid))
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question upfront I don't think you can use CNNs for your problem. Generally when people say they are using CNNs they usually mean the 2D convolution. It is operated on 2D spatial data (images). In NLP there exists 1D Convolution which people use to find local patterns in sequentual data. I don't think 1D convolution is relevant in your case. If you are from ML background you can think of regression using feed forward neural networks as polynomial regression. Intuitively you let the network decide which polynomial degree should we use to fit the data properly

Answer (score 1):

You can add 2Dconvnet-layers like this:

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(3, 150, 150)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
```

where

```
model.add(Conv2D(<feature maps>, (<kernel size>), input_shape=(<imput-tensor-shape)))
```

But be careful, 2Dconfnet-layers are mathematically different than dense-layers, so you can't stack them easily. To stack 2Dconvnet-layers with dense layers, you'll have to flatten them (you'll normally do this at the end to get your "fully-connected layer"):

```
model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

You'll find a lot of good tutorials on creating conv-nets with keras. [This one](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) for example focuses on image recognition. The examples above are taken from this article.

To find out, what a convolutional network does, I'd recommend you this [article](https://adeshpande3.github.io/adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/<0).

Edit:
But I share the opinion, that it might not be useful to use 2DConvnet layers for your example. Your data structure seems kind of "flat" and 2Dconvnets only make sense, when you have some multidimensional tensors as inputs.